# read the first integer of the first line of a txt file in Java

Tags: java, input, io

I am stuck here... I have in a txt file with a few (int) 2D arrays separated by a blank. the first line that precede each 2D array is the dimension of the array. (2D arrays are squared : #rows = #columns = dim)

4

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

at this stage I want to be able to read the dimension (dim =4) of the array on the first line. place the 2D array from the file into a 2D array and display it

how to I get the integer on the first line? any insight?
here what I have so far:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileInput));

dim= 4; //this value should be read from the first line

        array = new int[4][4];
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            for (int row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < dim; column++) {
                    array[row][column] = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.print(array[row][column]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        scan.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]); 
            }
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: ?? You know how to read integers from the text of successive rows but not the first row?

Comment: this is correct! when i tried to enter the first value int FirstVal =scan.NextInt() then the first integer of the next line is not read !!

Comment: Obviously this makes no sense. Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

```
String fileInput = "input.txt";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileInput));
int dim = 1; 
int[][] array = null;
int counter = 0; 
while (scan.hasNext()) 
{
    if (counter++ == 0)
    {
        dim = scan.nextInt();
        array = new int[dim][dim];
        continue;
    }
    int i = (counter-2)/dim ;
    int j = (counter-2)%dim ; 
    array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

    if (i == dim - 1  && j == dim - 1 )
    {
        counter = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

scan.close();
```

I tested it with your input of

4

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

the output is

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

then I tested it with this input:

4

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

5

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4

and the output is

1234

5678

1234

5678

01234

56789

01234

56789

01234

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you wanted to do?

Instead of manually assigning a value to dim, This program reads dim form the file

```
int dim = scan.nextInt();
```

Here is the full code.

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File fileInput = new File("file.txt");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileInput);

        int dim = scan.nextInt(); //this value should be read from the first line

        int[][] array = new int[dim][dim];

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            for (int row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < dim; column++) {
                    array[row][column] = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }

        }
        scan.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```